# D3 Simulation not working after slider event

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a bubblechart with collision detection which changes the radius with a slider.
The simulation is defined as below:

```
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("x", d3.forceX(width/2).strength(0.05))
  .force("y", d3.forceY(height/2).strength(0.05))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d){
    return scaleRadius(d.value)+1;
  }));
```

After the slider is manipulated, I call a function, which in turn calls the below code:

```
var circles = d3.selectAll(".circlesvg")
circles.selectAll(".artist").data(datapoints)
  .transition()
  .attr("r", function(d){
  return d.value;
  })
```

Because the radius can get bigger, I need to rerun the simulation to check for collision and have the DOMs translate appropriately. However the simulation code does not seem to be doing anything.

```
simulation.nodes(datapoints)
  .on("tick", ticked)
```

I am wondering if I do not have the right binding between simulation and the nodes.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After passing the new data...

```
simulation.nodes(data);
```

...you have to re-heat the simulation:

```
simulation.alpha(0.8).restart();
```

Here is a very simplified demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var colour = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var data = [{r: 10},{r: 5},{r: 15},{r: 20},{r: 9},
{r: 30},{r: 12},{r: 7},{r: 26},{r: 17}];

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)
    .force("x", d3.forceX(150).strength(0.05))
    .force("y", d3.forceY(75).strength(0.05))
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) {
        return d.r + 1;
    }));

var node = svg.selectAll(".circles")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", d => d.r)
    .attr("fill", (d,i)=> colour(i))

simulation.nodes(data)
    .on("tick", d => {
        node.attr("cx", d => d.x).attr("cy", d => d.y);
    });

d3.select("button").on("click", () => {
    data.forEach(d => d.r = Math.random() * 30);
    node.transition().duration(500).attr("r", d => d.r);
    simulation.nodes(data);
    simulation.alpha(0.8).restart();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<button>Randomize</button>
<svg></svg>
```